# Characteristic of an integral domain without unit element must be prime?

Tags: ring-theory

I want to show that if an integral domain $D$ has finite characteristic, its characteristic must be prime.

This is easy enough if we assume that $D$ has a unit element, but the textbook I'm using (Herstein, Topics in Algebra) does not require there to be a unit element in an integral domain.

Comment: Hint: $na^{2} = 0$ for all $a\in D$. What can be said if n has non-trivial factors?